# How can you update the text views every two seconds With JSON?

Tags: android, json

I tried a Timer task but that doesn't help
I was trying to get the code to continuously get the and update Coordinates.
I v'e done research but none applies to what I'm using.
Would I put the onPostExecute inside the timer ?

I'm using a json OBJECT.

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    TextView latitude;
    TextView longitude;
    String lat;
    String longit;
    JSONObject jobj = null;

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition tryAgain = lock.newCondition();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
        latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);
        longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);


        new retrievedata().execute();
    }

    class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... args) {

            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");


                    try {
                        lat = "latitude : " + jobj.getString("latitude");
                        longit = "longitude : " + jobj.getString("longitude");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            return lat;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String lat) {


            latitude.setText(lat);
            longitude.setText(longit);

        }




     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen by your questions over the past couple of days that you are struggling with this, so I will try to help out here.

Here's one way to do the timer part:  `AsyncTask` has a means whereby you can report progress.  When you call `publishProgress` within `doInBackground`, it will cause `onProgressUpdate` to be called on the UI thread.  You can use these methods to do your updates.

```
// by convention class names begin with an uppercase letter in Java
class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            while (! isCancelled()) {

                jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");

                String lat = "latitude : " + jobj.getString("latitude");
                String long = "longitude : " + jobj.getString("longitude");

                // this will cause onProgressUpdate to be called with lat & long
                publishProgress(lat, long);

                // it's okay to sleep within the background thread
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.w("RetrieveData", "thread was interrupted", e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("RetrieveData", "parse error", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        latitude.setText(values[0]);
        longitude.setText(values[1]);
    }

}
```

Also, for best results I think you should have a reference to the task and manage it in your activity with `onPause` and `onResume` like this:

```
    private AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> retrieveData;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        retrieveData = new RetrieveData();
        retrieveData.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        retrieveData.cancel(true);
        retrieveData = null;
        super.onPause();
    }
```

This means you don't need to call task `execute` in `onCreate`.

This may not be the very best approach, but it's probably the simplest way just to get you started — until somebody else gives you a better answer.