# AsyncTask stops when app is killed

Tags: android, json

My code runs fine, but if I go back to the home screen and return the code stops running on the text view shows nothing. Shouldn't it restart when I return to the page? It throws no errors, but if I eliminate the task and initialize the app it all over again it works but I must stay on that activity because If I go to Home and return it stops.

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    TextView latitude;
    TextView longitude;
    String lat;
    String longit;
    JSONObject jobj = null;

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition tryAgain = lock.newCondition();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
        latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);
        longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);


        new Retrievedata().execute();
    }

    class Retrievedata extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                while (!isCancelled()) {

                    jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");

                    String lat = "latitude : " + jobj.getString("latitude");
                    String longit ="longitude : " + jobj.getString("longitude");

                    // this will cause onProgressUpdate to be called with lat & long
                    publishProgress(lat,longit);

                    // it's okay to sleep within the background thread
                    Thread.sleep(1500);

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w("RetrieveData", "thread was interrupted", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("RetrieveData", "parse error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            latitude.setText(values[0]);
            longitude.setText(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't but when I run it in the emulator it has problems

Comment: From main screen to this screen the code runs

Comment: But If i go back then return to this activity/Screen The code stops working

Comment: It didn't crash

Comment: Maybe I need a screen shot?

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=5657bcd6b243dbc8_0.1&zw

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.2&disp=safe&realattid=dc0980ef892aee10_0.1&zw

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.3&disp=safe&realattid=4087728d69fc0d84_0.1&zw

Comment: They link to my screen shots

Comment: I'm tracking a satellite

Comment: If you kill the app, the `AsyncTask` stops too.

Comment: Yes, But I need It to be consistent when I go from home page to This page      .  And vice versa

Comment: consistent ? How? I didn't get you.

Comment: I don't see why when I enter the page the code works https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.2&disp=safe&realattid=dc0980ef892aee10_0.1&zw

Comment: Then if i go to the home page   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.3&disp=safe&realattid=4087728d69fc0d84_0.1&zw  and return it gives me this

Comment: then it give me this when i return https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?ui=2&ik=4224c620e2&view=att&th=1584c58e0320dbe3&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=5657bcd6b243dbc8_0.1&zw

Comment: Try add the pictures to your question.

Comment: I can only show the links

Comment: create Retrievedata instance as a member of IsstatusActivity and call it onResume(). or saveInstance . or use a handler to call it continuosly with an interval

Comment: Go look carefully at the end of my answer that got you into this situation, my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40496875/4504191 If you start the task in `onResume` and stop the task in `onPause` that should alleviate this problem.

Comment: Incidentally, the people telling you to avoid `AsyncTask` and use a `Service` are indeed correct.  Since you're pretty new to Android, I thought you should start with an easy approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it restart when I return to the page?

Not necessarily. From the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

So by default the execution of `AsyncTask`s on versions of Android from Honeycomb onwards is serialised, meaning that only one can execute at any given time.

Looking at `Retrievedata`, it is set up to loop until it is cancelled (or it is interrupted or encounters a JSON related exception). However, the task isn't ever cancelled in `IsstatusActivity` (say, in `onDestroy()`), so barring interruptions or errors it will run forever (or at least until your app is killed).

Part of the reason for this is that `AsyncTask`s are not tied to the activity lifecycle. That means that they don't get automatically stopped when the activity they were created in finishes - rather, they keep on running until they finish whatever they're tasked with doing. Again, because `Retrievedata` loops until it's cancelled and this never happens, it will happily block the execution of new instances of `Retrievedata` created when the `IsstatusActivity` is subsequently started again (not to mention any other `AsyncTask` instances you may be using in other activities).

For more background I recommend checking out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147992/2259854
- http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/

You may be able to solve the issue by cancelling the task when you finish the activity, but as other posters have stated it may be better to avoid using `AsyncTask` at all for this kind of task. My understanding of `AsyncTask` is that it is best used for short running operations - indeed, this is what the documentation says:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

As an aside, there's another issue with the code posted. As `Retrievedata` is an inner class (as opposed to being static) of `IsstatusActivity`, each instance of it will keep an implicit reference to the instance of `IsstatusActivity` it was created in. This means that even after you finish any given instance of `IsstatusActivity`, it will remain in memory until the `Retrievedata` instance created within it has finished and can be garbage collected. As per the above, this will never happen because the task runs forever.

This is called activity/context leaking. Every time `IsstatusActivity` is started and finished, the instance will hang around consuming memory until the app is killed. Activities are heavy objects so this is definitely something to be avoided.

Hope that helps!